# Add target="_blank" to menu item of type MENU_LOCAL_ACTION

Tags: navigation

How can I add a target="_blank" property to a menu item of type MENU_LOCAL_ACTION ? I cannot do 'options' on MENU_LOCAL_TASK, MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, and MENU_LOCAL_ACTION items.
I tried with jQuery

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.page-admin-commerce-reports-incomplete-payments .action_links li a[href]').attr({
            target: "_blank",
            title: "Opens in a new window"
        })
    });
}(jQuery));
```

But it didn't work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a module for this: [Menu target](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_target).

In case you need to do it programmatically, you can have a look at the [source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/menu_target/tree/) for inspiration. As far as I see, the module adds a special class to the menu items you select, and then some JS captures the click and opens a new window:

```
  $('a.target-blank', context).once('target-blank', function () {
    $(this).click(function() {
      window.open(this.href);
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I misspelled the class name!
`.action-links` **not** `.action_links`
My fault, the jQuery code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. It works with Drupal 8 as far as I know